# React JS - check if an array of objects includes more objects in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

Please help me. all I want is show the `<div className="songs-list-header-col">Album</div>` only when the tracks array includes the `artist` property as an object. I have some scenarios where artist is not an object there I don't want show the `<div>`. what should I do.

```
tracks [
0:{
   album: {id: 1, album_name: "Fearless (Taylor's Version)"}
   artist: {id: 1, artist_name: "Taylor Swift"}
   genre: "POP"
   id: 1
   time: "00:03:49"
   track_name: "Love Story"
},
1: {
   album: {id: 1, album_name: "Fearless (Taylor's Version)"}
   artist: {id: 1, artist_name: "Taylor Swift"}
   genre: "POP"
   id: 2
   time: "00:03:40"
   track_name: "You Belong With Me"
},
2: {
   album: {id: 2, album_name: "Divide"}
   artist: {id: 2, artist_name: "Ed Sheeran"}
   genre: "POP"
   id: 4
   time: "00:04:23"
   track_name: "Perfect"
}
]
```

I know map is not the solution but I tried it it is giving the solution but just like map works it prints the div 3 times. but all I want is that check if `artist` is an object or not. if it's object print div.

```
{
  tracks.map((track) => {
    return (
      typeof track.artist === 'object' &&
        <div className="songs-list-header-col">Album</div>
    )
  })
}
```

and also I'm not able to directly check like `tracks[0].artist` it gives the type error. what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
tracks.filter(track => typeof track.artist === 'object')
      .map(track => <div className="songs-list-header-col">Album</div>)
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives ReferenceError: object is not defined.

Comment: I fixed the example now

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.